# Musixtex alaligne command not working with changepage package

Tags: musixtex

It is needed to use Musixtex alaligne command to work with changepage package to use the whole width page. The basic code is as follow:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{musicography}
%\usepackage{undar-digitacion}

\usepackage{musixtex}
\input musixlyr
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=1.3cm}


\usepackage{changepage}% Para setear el ancho de uso de la página
\newlength{\musicwidthtable}%new
\setlength{\musicwidthtable}{1.1\textwidth}%new, can be set for each 


\begin{document}


\section{Diagrama de Digitación de la Quena en G, }
\vspace*{1.2cm}
\begin{adjustwidth}{-1.2cm}{-1.3cm}%Paquete changepage
\begin{music}
    \hsize=\musicwidthtable
    %\resetlyrics
    \nolyr
    \lyricsoff
    \font\A=phvb8t at 6pt% added for letter type.
    \parindent0mm
    %\largemusicsize
    \nobarnumbers
    %\generalmeter{\meterfrac44}%
    \startpiece 
    %\startextract
    %\nolyr
    %\lyricsoff
    \notes%\zcharnote u{\addTres{BbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote n{\A G$_3$}%
    \wh{N}\en%\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote u{\addTres{BbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote n{\A G\musSharp{}$_3$}%
    \wh{^N}\en%\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote u{\addTres{BbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote n{\A A$_3$}%
    \wh{a}\en%\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote u{\addDos{CbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote n{\A A\musSharp{}$_3$}%
    \wh{^a}\en%\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote u{\addTres{BbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote n{\A B$_3$}%
    \wh{b}\en%\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote u{\addUno{DbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote n{\A C$_4$}%
    \wh{c}\en%\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote u{\addUno{DbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote n{\A C\musSharp{}$_4$}%
    \wh{^c}\en%\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote u{\addCero{EbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote n{\A D$_4$}%
    \wh{d}\en%\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote u{\addCero{EbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote n{\A D\musSharp{}$_4$}%
    \wh{^d}\en%\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote u{\addCuatro{GbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote n{\A E$_4$}%
    \wh{e}\en%\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote u{\addCuatro{GbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote n{\A F$_4$}%
    \wh{f}\en%\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote u{\addCero{EbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote n{\A F\musSharp{}$_4$}%
    \wh{^f}\en\bar%
    \notes%\zcharnote u{\addCuatro{GbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote n{\A G$_4$}%
    \wh{g}\en%\bar%
    \notes%\zcharnote u{\addCero{EbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote n{\A G\musSharp{}$_4$}%
    \wh{^g}\en%\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote u{\addTres{BbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote n{\A A$_4$}%
    \wh{h}\en%\bar%
    \notes%\zcharnote u{\addCero{EbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote n{\A A\musSharp{}$_4$}%
    \wh{^h}\en%\bar%
    \notes%\zcharnote u{\addDos{CbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote n{\A B$_4$}%
    \wh{i}\en%\bar%
    \notes%\zcharnote w{\addUno{DbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote a{\A C$_5$}%
    \wh{j}\en%\bar%
    \notes%\zcharnote u{\addUno{DbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote a{\A C\musSharp{}$_5$}%
    \wh{^j}\en%\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote w{\addCero{EbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote a{\A D$_5$}%
    \wh{k}\en%\bar%
    \notes%\zcharnote u{\addUno{DbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote a{\A D\musSharp{}$_5$}%
    \wh{^k}\en%\bar%
    \notes%\zcharnote w{\addTres{CbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote a{\A E$_5$}%
    \wh{l}\en%\bar%
    \notes%\zcharnote w{\addDos{DbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote a{\A F$_5$}%
    \wh{m}\en%\bar%
    \notes%\zcharnote u{\addUno{DbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote a{\A F\musSharp{}$_5$}%
    \wh{^m}\en\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote w{\addUno{CbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote a{\A G$_5$}%
    \wh{n}\en%\bar%
    \notes%\zcharnote u{\addUno{DbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote a{\A G\musSharp{}$_5$}%
    \wh{^n}\en%\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote w{\addTres{BbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote a{\A A$_5$}%
    \wh{o}\en%\bar%
    \notes%\zcharnote u{\addUno{DbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote a{\A A\musSharp{}$_5$}%
    \wh{^o}\en%\bar%
    \notes%\zcharnote w{\addDos{CbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote a{\A B$_5$}%
    \wh{p}\en%\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote z{\addUno{DbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote a{\A C$_6$}%
    \wh{q}\en%\bar%
    \notes%\zcharnote u{\addUno{DbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote a{\A C\musSharp{}$_6$}%
    \wh{^q}\en%\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote z{\addUnoA{EbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote a{\A D$_6$}%
    \wh{r}\en%\bar%
    \notes%\zcharnote u{\addUno{DbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote a{\A D\musSharp{}$_6$}%
    \wh{^r}\en%\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote z{\addDosA{EbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote a{\A E$_6$}%
    \wh{s}\en%\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote z{\addCero{EbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote a{\A F$_6$}%
    \wh{t}\en%\bar%
    \alaligne%\bar
    \notes%\zcharnote u{\addTres{BbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote n{\A G$_3$}%
    \wh{N}\en%\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote u{\addTres{BbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote n{\A G\musSharp{}$_3$}%
    \wh{^N}\en%\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote u{\addTres{BbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote n{\A A$_3$}%
    \wh{a}\en%\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote u{\addDos{CbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote n{\A A\musSharp{}$_3$}%
    \wh{^a}\en%\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote u{\addTres{BbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote n{\A B$_3$}%
    \wh{b}\en%\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote u{\addUno{DbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote n{\A C$_4$}%
    \wh{c}\en%\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote u{\addUno{DbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote n{\A C\musSharp{}$_4$}%
    \wh{^c}\en%\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote u{\addCero{EbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote n{\A D$_4$}%
    \wh{d}\en%\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote u{\addCero{EbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote n{\A D\musSharp{}$_4$}%
    \wh{^d}\en%\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote u{\addCuatro{GbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote n{\A E$_4$}%
    \wh{e}\en%\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote u{\addCuatro{GbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote n{\A F$_4$}%
    \wh{f}\en%\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote u{\addCero{EbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote n{\A F\musSharp{}$_4$}%
    \wh{^f}\en\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote u{\addCuatro{GbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote n{\A G$_4$}%
    \wh{g}\en%\bar%
    \notes%\zcharnote u{\addCero{EbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote n{\A G\musSharp{}$_4$}%
    \wh{^g}\en%\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote u{\addTres{BbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote n{\A A$_4$}%
    \wh{h}\en%\bar%
    \notes%\zcharnote u{\addCero{EbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote n{\A A\musSharp{}$_4$}%
    \wh{^h}\en%\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote u{\addDos{CbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote n{\A B$_4$}%
    \wh{i}\en%\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote w{\addUno{DbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote a{\A C$_5$}%
    \wh{j}\en%\bar%
    \notes%\zcharnote u{\addUno{DbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote a{\A C\musSharp{}$_5$}%
    \wh{^j}\en%\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote w{\addCero{EbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote a{\A D$_5$}%
    \wh{k}\en%\bar%
    \notes%\zcharnote u{\addUno{DbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote a{\A D\musSharp{}$_5$}%
    \wh{^k}\en%\bar%
    \notes%\zcharnote w{\addTres{CbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote a{\A E$_5$}%
    \wh{l}\en%\bar%
    \notes%\zcharnote w{\addDos{DbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote a{\A F$_5$}%
    \wh{m}\en%\bar%
    \notes%\zcharnote u{\addUno{DbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote a{\A F\musSharp{}$_5$}%
    \wh{^m}\en\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote w{\addUno{CbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote a{\A G$_5$}%
    \wh{n}\en%\bar%
    \notes%\zcharnote u{\addUno{DbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote a{\A G\musSharp{}$_5$}%
    \wh{^n}\en%\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote w{\addTres{BbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote a{\A A$_5$}%
    \wh{o}\en%\bar%
    \notes%\zcharnote u{\addUno{DbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote a{\A A\musSharp{}$_5$}%
    \wh{^o}\en%\bar%
    \notes%\zcharnote w{\addDos{CbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote a{\A B$_5$}%
    \wh{p}\en%\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote z{\addUno{DbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote a{\A C$_6$}%
    \wh{q}\en%\bar%
    \notes%\zcharnote u{\addUno{DbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote a{\A C\musSharp{}$_6$}%
    \wh{^q}\en%\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote z{\addUnoA{EbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote a{\A D$_6$}%
    \wh{r}\en%\bar%
    \notes%\zcharnote u{\addUno{DbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote a{\A D\musSharp{}$_6$}%
    \wh{^r}\en%\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote z{\addDosA{EbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote a{\A E$_6$}%
    \wh{s}\en%\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote z{\addCero{EbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote a{\A F$_6$}%
    \wh{t}\en%\bar%
    %\endextract
    \Endpiece
\end{music}   
\end{adjustwidth}

\end{document}
```

The current output is as follow:
[image]

Note that only two rows should be plotted instead of four rows...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why `1.1\textwidth`? Inside `adjustwidth` you have the correct value in `\linewidth`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{musicography}
%\usepackage{undar-digitacion}

\usepackage{musixtex}
\input musixlyr
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=1.3cm}


\usepackage{changepage}% Para setear el ancho de uso de la página
%\newlength{\musicwidthtable}%new
%\setlength{\musicwidthtable}{1.1\textwidth}%new, can be set for each 


\begin{document}


\section{Diagrama de Digitación de la Quena en G, }
\vspace*{1.2cm}
\begin{adjustwidth}{-1.2cm}{-1.3cm}%Paquete changepage
\begin{music}
    \hsize=\linewidth
    %\resetlyrics
    \nolyr
    \lyricsoff
    \begingroup
    \fontsize{6}{0}\usefont{OT1}{phv}{m}{n}%
    \expandafter\endgroup\expandafter\let\expandafter\A\the\font
%    \font\A=phvb8t at 6pt% added for letter type.
    \parindent0mm
    %\largemusicsize
    \nobarnumbers
    %\generalmeter{\meterfrac44}%
    \startpiece 
    %\startextract
    %\nolyr
    %\lyricsoff
    \notes%\zcharnote u{\addTres{BbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote n{\A G$_3$}%
    \wh{N}\en%\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote u{\addTres{BbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote n{\A G\musSharp{}$_3$}%
    \wh{^N}\en%\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote u{\addTres{BbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote n{\A A$_3$}%
    \wh{a}\en%\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote u{\addDos{CbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote n{\A A\musSharp{}$_3$}%
    \wh{^a}\en%\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote u{\addTres{BbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote n{\A B$_3$}%
    \wh{b}\en%\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote u{\addUno{DbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote n{\A C$_4$}%
    \wh{c}\en%\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote u{\addUno{DbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote n{\A C\musSharp{}$_4$}%
    \wh{^c}\en%\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote u{\addCero{EbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote n{\A D$_4$}%
    \wh{d}\en%\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote u{\addCero{EbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote n{\A D\musSharp{}$_4$}%
    \wh{^d}\en%\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote u{\addCuatro{GbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote n{\A E$_4$}%
    \wh{e}\en%\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote u{\addCuatro{GbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote n{\A F$_4$}%
    \wh{f}\en%\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote u{\addCero{EbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote n{\A F\musSharp{}$_4$}%
    \wh{^f}\en\bar%
    \notes%\zcharnote u{\addCuatro{GbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote n{\A G$_4$}%
    \wh{g}\en%\bar%
    \notes%\zcharnote u{\addCero{EbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote n{\A G\musSharp{}$_4$}%
    \wh{^g}\en%\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote u{\addTres{BbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote n{\A A$_4$}%
    \wh{h}\en%\bar%
    \notes%\zcharnote u{\addCero{EbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote n{\A A\musSharp{}$_4$}%
    \wh{^h}\en%\bar%
    \notes%\zcharnote u{\addDos{CbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote n{\A B$_4$}%
    \wh{i}\en%\bar%
    \notes%\zcharnote w{\addUno{DbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote a{\A C$_5$}%
    \wh{j}\en%\bar%
    \notes%\zcharnote u{\addUno{DbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote a{\A C\musSharp{}$_5$}%
    \wh{^j}\en%\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote w{\addCero{EbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote a{\A D$_5$}%
    \wh{k}\en%\bar%
    \notes%\zcharnote u{\addUno{DbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote a{\A D\musSharp{}$_5$}%
    \wh{^k}\en%\bar%
    \notes%\zcharnote w{\addTres{CbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote a{\A E$_5$}%
    \wh{l}\en%\bar%
    \notes%\zcharnote w{\addDos{DbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote a{\A F$_5$}%
    \wh{m}\en%\bar%
    \notes%\zcharnote u{\addUno{DbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote a{\A F\musSharp{}$_5$}%
    \wh{^m}\en\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote w{\addUno{CbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote a{\A G$_5$}%
    \wh{n}\en%\bar%
    \notes%\zcharnote u{\addUno{DbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote a{\A G\musSharp{}$_5$}%
    \wh{^n}\en%\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote w{\addTres{BbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote a{\A A$_5$}%
    \wh{o}\en%\bar%
    \notes%\zcharnote u{\addUno{DbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote a{\A A\musSharp{}$_5$}%
    \wh{^o}\en%\bar%
    \notes%\zcharnote w{\addDos{CbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote a{\A B$_5$}%
    \wh{p}\en%\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote z{\addUno{DbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote a{\A C$_6$}%
    \wh{q}\en%\bar%
    \notes%\zcharnote u{\addUno{DbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote a{\A C\musSharp{}$_6$}%
    \wh{^q}\en%\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote z{\addUnoA{EbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote a{\A D$_6$}%
    \wh{r}\en%\bar%
    \notes%\zcharnote u{\addUno{DbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote a{\A D\musSharp{}$_6$}%
    \wh{^r}\en%\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote z{\addDosA{EbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote a{\A E$_6$}%
    \wh{s}\en%\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote z{\addCero{EbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote a{\A F$_6$}%
    \wh{t}\en%\bar%
    \alaligne%\bar
    \notes%\zcharnote u{\addTres{BbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote n{\A G$_3$}%
    \wh{N}\en%\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote u{\addTres{BbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote n{\A G\musSharp{}$_3$}%
    \wh{^N}\en%\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote u{\addTres{BbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote n{\A A$_3$}%
    \wh{a}\en%\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote u{\addDos{CbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote n{\A A\musSharp{}$_3$}%
    \wh{^a}\en%\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote u{\addTres{BbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote n{\A B$_3$}%
    \wh{b}\en%\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote u{\addUno{DbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote n{\A C$_4$}%
    \wh{c}\en%\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote u{\addUno{DbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote n{\A C\musSharp{}$_4$}%
    \wh{^c}\en%\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote u{\addCero{EbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote n{\A D$_4$}%
    \wh{d}\en%\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote u{\addCero{EbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote n{\A D\musSharp{}$_4$}%
    \wh{^d}\en%\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote u{\addCuatro{GbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote n{\A E$_4$}%
    \wh{e}\en%\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote u{\addCuatro{GbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote n{\A F$_4$}%
    \wh{f}\en%\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote u{\addCero{EbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote n{\A F\musSharp{}$_4$}%
    \wh{^f}\en\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote u{\addCuatro{GbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote n{\A G$_4$}%
    \wh{g}\en%\bar%
    \notes%\zcharnote u{\addCero{EbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote n{\A G\musSharp{}$_4$}%
    \wh{^g}\en%\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote u{\addTres{BbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote n{\A A$_4$}%
    \wh{h}\en%\bar%
    \notes%\zcharnote u{\addCero{EbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote n{\A A\musSharp{}$_4$}%
    \wh{^h}\en%\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote u{\addDos{CbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote n{\A B$_4$}%
    \wh{i}\en%\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote w{\addUno{DbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote a{\A C$_5$}%
    \wh{j}\en%\bar%
    \notes%\zcharnote u{\addUno{DbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote a{\A C\musSharp{}$_5$}%
    \wh{^j}\en%\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote w{\addCero{EbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote a{\A D$_5$}%
    \wh{k}\en%\bar%
    \notes%\zcharnote u{\addUno{DbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote a{\A D\musSharp{}$_5$}%
    \wh{^k}\en%\bar%
    \notes%\zcharnote w{\addTres{CbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote a{\A E$_5$}%
    \wh{l}\en%\bar%
    \notes%\zcharnote w{\addDos{DbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote a{\A F$_5$}%
    \wh{m}\en%\bar%
    \notes%\zcharnote u{\addUno{DbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote a{\A F\musSharp{}$_5$}%
    \wh{^m}\en\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote w{\addUno{CbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote a{\A G$_5$}%
    \wh{n}\en%\bar%
    \notes%\zcharnote u{\addUno{DbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote a{\A G\musSharp{}$_5$}%
    \wh{^n}\en%\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote w{\addTres{BbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote a{\A A$_5$}%
    \wh{o}\en%\bar%
    \notes%\zcharnote u{\addUno{DbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote a{\A A\musSharp{}$_5$}%
    \wh{^o}\en%\bar%
    \notes%\zcharnote w{\addDos{CbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote a{\A B$_5$}%
    \wh{p}\en%\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote z{\addUno{DbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote a{\A C$_6$}%
    \wh{q}\en%\bar%
    \notes%\zcharnote u{\addUno{DbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote a{\A C\musSharp{}$_6$}%
    \wh{^q}\en%\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote z{\addUnoA{EbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote a{\A D$_6$}%
    \wh{r}\en%\bar%
    \notes%\zcharnote u{\addUno{DbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote a{\A D\musSharp{}$_6$}%
    \wh{^r}\en%\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote z{\addDosA{EbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote a{\A E$_6$}%
    \wh{s}\en%\bar%
    \Notes%\zcharnote z{\addCero{EbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote a{\A F$_6$}%
    \wh{t}\en%\bar%
    %\endextract
    \Endpiece
\end{music}   
\end{adjustwidth}

\end{document}
```

I'd avoid `\font` in LaTeX, but feel free to use it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is not meant as an modification of the solution egreg gave and which I implemented here, but an improvement of your original code (so do not accept it, but just learn from it), because you use the capital N in `\notes` arbitrarily with an undesired result, you waste space around the bars, of which the last on line 1 only can be guessed to be there, but not really seen, you end your scale arbitrarily on f instead on f sharp, and: you do not at all present the chromatic scale of G major, but the chromatic scale of C major, starting on G - where you are starting to count, I can only guess, actually you should start just in g without any subscript number. According to me, the first line is what would fit your intention. Don't forget to `\musixflx` and set the code again.

```
    \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
    \usepackage[spanish]{babel}
    \usepackage{musicography}
    %\usepackage{undar-digitacion}
    
    \usepackage{musixtex}
    \input musixlyr
    \usepackage{geometry}
    \geometry{margin=1.3cm}
    
    
    \usepackage{changepage}% Para setear el ancho de uso de la página
    \newlength{\musicwidthtable}%new
    %\setlength{\musicwidthtable}{1.1\textwidth}%new, can be set for each 
    
    
    \begin{document}
    \section{Diagrama de Digitación de la Quena en G, }%
    \vspace*{1.2cm}%
    \begin{adjustwidth}{-1.2cm}{-1.2cm}%Paquete changepage to make the last bar in line 1 visible
    \begin{musi

c}%
    \hsize=\linewidth%
    %\resetlyrics
    \nolyr%
    \lyricsoff%
    \font\A=phvb8t at 8pt% added for letter type. to make the letter better readable 
    \parindent0mm%
    %\largemusicsize
    \nobarnumbers%
    %\generalmeter{\meterfrac44}%
    \footnotesize%  to make the subscript smaller
    \startpiece%
    %\startextract
    %\nolyr
    %\lyricsoff
    \notes%\zcharnote u{\addTres{BbG}{blue}}% notes is enough and distributes the notes equally
    \zcharnote n{\A g}\wh{N}% deleted \en \notes to make the code more transparent
    \zcharnote n{\A g\musSharp{}}\wh{^N}%
    \zcharnote n{\A a}\wh{a}%
    \zcharnote n{\A a\musSharp{}}\wh{^a}%
    \zcharnote n{\A b}\wh{b}%
    \zcharnote n{\A c$_1$}\wh{c}%
    \zcharnote n{\A c\musSharp{}$_1$}\wh{^c}%
    \zcharnote n{\A d$_1$}\wh{d}%
    \zcharnote n{\A d\musSharp{}$_1$}\wh{^d}%
    \zcharnote n{\A e$_1$}\wh{e}%
    \zcharnote n{\A e\musSharp{}$_1$}\wh{^e}% this is the 11th note in G scharp
    \zcharnote n{\A f\musSharp{}$_1$}\wh{^f}\hbsk\qsk\en\bar%  to tighten the space before the bar
    %
    \notes\hbsk\qqsk%\zcharnote u{\addCuatro{GbG}{blue}}% to tighten the space after the bar
    \zcharnote n{\A g$_1$}\wh{g}%
    \zcharnote n{\A g\musSharp{}$_1$}\wh{^g}%
    \zcharnote n{\A a$_1$}\wh{h}%
    \zcharnote n{\A a\musSharp{}$_1$}\wh{^h}%
    \zcharnote n{\A b$_1$}\wh{i}%
    \zcharnote a{\A c$_2$}\wh{j}%
    \zcharnote a{\A c\musSharp{}$_2$}\wh{^j}%
    \zcharnote a{\A d$_2$}\wh{k}%
    \zcharnote a{\A d\musSharp{}$_2$}\wh{^k}%
    \zcharnote a{\A e$_2$}\wh{l}%
    \zcharnote a{\A e\musSharp{}$_2$}\wh{^l}%
    \zcharnote a{\A f\musSharp{}$_2$}\wh{^m}\hbsk\qsk\en\bar%
    %
    \notes\hbsk\qqsk%\zcharnote w{\addUno{CbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote a{\A g$_2$}\wh{n}%
    \zcharnote a{\A g\musSharp{}$_2$}\wh{^n}%
    \zcharnote a{\A a$_2$}\wh{o}%
    \zcharnote a{\A a\musSharp{}$_2$}\wh{^o}%
    \zcharnote a{\A b$_2$}\wh{p}%
    \zcharnote a{\A c$_3$}\wh{q}%
    \zcharnote a{\A c\musSharp{}$_3$}\wh{^q}%
    \zcharnote a{\A d$_3$}\wh{r}%
    \zcharnote a{\A d\musSharp{}$_3$}\wh{^r}%
    \zcharnote a{\A e$_3$}\wh{s}%
    \zcharnote a{\A e\musSharp{}$_3$}\wh{^s}%
    \zcharnote a{\A f\musSharp{}$_3$}\wh{^t}\en% the scale should end here
    \alaligne%\bar
    %
   \addspace{-1\afterruleskip}% to create more space in the entire line
    \notes%\zcharnote u{\addTres{BbG}{blue}}%
    \zcharnote n{\A G$_3$}\wh{N}%
    \zcharnote n{\A G\musSharp{}$_3$}\wh{^N}%
    \zcharnote n{\A A$_3$}\wh{a}%
    \zcharnote n{\A A\musSharp{}$_3$}\wh{^a}%
    \zcharnote n{\A B$_3$}\wh{b}%
    \zcharnote n{\A C$_4$}\wh{c}%
    \zcharnote n{\A C\musSharp{}$_4$}\wh{^c}%
    \zcharnote n{\A D$_4$}\wh{d}%
    \zcharnote n{\A D\musSharp{}$_4$}\wh{^d}%
    \zcharnote n{\A E$_4$}\wh{e}%
    \zcharnote n{\A F$_4$}\wh{f}%
    \zcharnote n{\A F\musSharp{}$_4$}\wh{^f}\hbsk\qsk\en\bar%
    %
    \notes%\zcharnote u{\addCuatro{GbG}{blue}}%
    \hbsk\qqsk\zcharnote n{\A G$_4$}\wh{g}%
    \zcharnote n{\A G\musSharp{}$_4$}\wh{^g}%
    \zcharnote n{\A A$_4$}\wh{h}%
    \zcharnote n{\A A\musSharp{}$_4$}\wh{^h}%
    \zcharnote n{\A B$_4$}\wh{i}%
    \zcharnote a{\A C$_5$}\wh{j}%
    \zcharnote a{\A C\musSharp{}$_5$}\wh{^j}%
    \zcharnote a{\A D$_5$}\wh{k}%
    \zcharnote a{\A D\musSharp{}$_5$}\wh{^k}%
    \zcharnote a{\A E$_5$}\wh{l}%
    \zcharnote a{\A F$_5$}\wh{m}%
    \zcharnote a{\A F\musSharp{}$_5$}\wh{^m}\hbsk\qsk\en\bar%
    %
    \notes%\zcharnote w{\addUno{CbG}{blue}}%
    \hbsk\qqsk\zcharnote a{\A G$_5$}\wh{n}%
    \zcharnote a{\A G\musSharp{}$_5$}\wh{^n}%
    \zcharnote a{\A A$_5$}\wh{o}%
    \zcharnote a{\A A\musSharp{}$_5$}\wh{^o}%
    \zcharnote a{\A B$_5$}\wh{p}%
    \zcharnote a{\A C$_6$}\wh{q}%
    \zcharnote a{\A C\musSharp{}$_6$}\wh{^q}%
    \zcharnote a{\A D$_6$}\wh{r}%
    \zcharnote a{\A D\musSharp{}$_6$}\wh{^r}%
    \zcharnote a{\A E$_6$}\wh{s}%
    \zcharnote a{\A F$_6$}\wh{t}\en%\bar%
    %\endextract
    \Endpiece
    \end{music}   
    \end{adjustwidth}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is surely more aesthetic as the other solutions.

Comment: Hi Peters, just a curiosity... which operative system do you use, and what Latex environment do you use to \musixflx ?

Comment: @ABV: I use TeXShop to set, musixflx in Terminal (on an Apple) and then set again in TeXShop, in this case just "LaTeX". In past times I worked in a "plain" document in DOS on a Windows Computer and musixflx-ed there as well. It is a LUA script, see page 5 (chapter 1.3.1 of musixdoc.pdf) and musixflx.pdf.

Comment: Great !!! I tested using DOS command as follow:                                                                   Batch File (musixflx_batch.bat)
pdflatex %1
musixflx %1
pdflatex %1                                                                                                                     
Now we can use it as follow: .\musixflx_batch.bat file_name